# Let's Encrypt error with Amazon Linux with virtualenv

Tags: lets-encrypt, virtualenv

I download certbot-auto and ran

```
./certbot-auto certonly --standalone -d domain.com -m tech@domain.com --agree-tos -n --debug
```

I get below error that it is looking for virtualenv==15.1.0 but installed version is 16.0.0. Is it possible to let certbot-auto use version 16.0.0? What can I do to resolve this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/virtualenv", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3049, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3033, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3062, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 660, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 673, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 858, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'virtualenv==15.1.0' distribution was not found and is required by the application

   $ virtualenv --version
    16.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I've been search for this exact issue. I finally found the answer. First, you go into `/usr/bin` and delete the files called `virtualenv*`.

Then, install virtual with this command:

```
sudo /usr/bin/easy_install virtualenv
```

From there certbot works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Just uninstall and install virtualenv again, worked for me.

`pip uninstall virtualenv`

`pip install virtualenv`